# Is it possible to combine border-color with border-image in same element?

Tags: css, html-lists, border

In CSS it is perfectly possible to combine background-image and background-color, which I often use to style an element with a background color and lay a semi-transparent pattern over it, like I did with my navbar:

```
background-color: #fa4457;
background-image: url(../images/pattern/overlay.png);
```

or shorthand

```
background: #fa4457 url(../images/pattern/overlay.png);
```

The following image shows that my navbar has both a background color and a background image to create a paper-like effect, but the selected menu item has a solid white bottom-border.

[image]

if I use this code, it looks like this

```
border-image: url(../images/pattern/overlay.png) 0 0 10 repeat;
```

[image]

can I somehow combine this with

```
border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
```

Or is there any way which does not involve creating an extra element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have somehow found the solution.

This:

```
background: white url(../images/pattern/overlay.png) repeat;
border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

result in this:

[image]

thanks to justtry for pointing me in the right direction of using pseudo elements. I still don't quite understand why they behave this way though.

Answer (score 0):

You said that don't want to create extra elements, but maybe then just use  pseudo elements? like :before or :after on your items,
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: the border-bottom: 10px solid #fff; is on the pseudo element :before but I dont quite understand them yet..

Comment: for such pseudo-elements you should set - content : ''; to make it usable
could you insert you code in jsfiddle, I'll try to help on your example.

Comment: Oh, just saw that you have already found solution for your situation.